# Using Application.Workbooks.Open to open .txt file, but it cuts away long numbers

Tags: vba, txt

I have this script

```
Sub IMport()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B1:K200").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hent Data").Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A200").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hent Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Format:="Text"
    End If
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I'm using this script to open a txt file and copying it to an excel sheet.
The problem is the numbers in column A are 23 numbers long, so when it is opened in excel a lot of the numbers have been removed.

How can I prevent Excel cutting off a lot of the numbers?

Update:
i made a mistake and posted the VBA script where i tried to fix the problem.
the real script is:

```
Sub IMport()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:K200").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hent Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please give some lines of representative example data at least so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Format isn't a valid argument is it? But yes, formatting the numbers as text is probably your best bet.

Comment: 0123137268311000000039 1 08/07/2021 15.02.26 612 5394 8508 13902 AMC-1 1 1625787847 1035
0123137268311000000039 2 08/07/2021 15.17.40 645 6831 12411 19242 AMC-1 1 1625787849 1035

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Excel while opening text file interprete the string of digits separated with delimiter as a  number, integer or float.
To avoid this you must use formatting options to treat the input as text, not as numbers.

Example.
Suppose that input text contains no more than 2 numeric fields separated with space(s)
The method
Workbooks.OpenText FileName:= "sample number list.txt", Space=True, FieldInfo=Array(Array(1,2),Array(2,2))

will perform input to first two columns of the new worksheet with no text to number conversion

FieldInfo parameter contains array of formatting options for each field of input file

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this a lot because I made the dumb mistake of generating  barcode numbers that may have a leading zero. Excel cuts off the leading zero on numbers and kept ruining those barcode numbers.

The solution I found was to first take the unchanged values into an array, and then add an equals sign and quotes around the value so when it is pasted into excel, it is a literal string and cannot be changed by their number formatting.

In my experience simply setting the sheets number formatting to "@" was not enough, excel would still try to remove leading zeroes on numbers and still try to display long numbers in scientific notation. But entering a number as `"=""" & number & """"` will force excel to not do that.

Here's the function I wrote to do this to a 2D array:

```vb
Private Function ForceString(ByRef InputArr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim OutputArr() As Variant
    OutputArr = InputArr
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(OutputArr) To UBound(OutputArr)
        For j = LBound(OutputArr, 2) To UBound(OutputArr, 2)
            OutputArr(i, j) = "=""" & OutputArr(i, j) & """"
        Next j
    Next i
    ForceString = OutputArr
End Function
```